# I am trying to put php variable in side sparql query

Tags: php, sparql

I am writing a PHP code and inside in a sparql query I need to put a variable I tried
 '. $search . ' but it do not work

Part from the code is (the sparql query):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?title  WHERE {

?book dct:creator ?author ;

dct:title ?title.

?author foaf:name   '. $search . ' ;

OPTIONAL {?book bibo:isbn10 ?isbn} OPTIONAL {?book bibo:ibsn13 ?isbn} }';

?>
```

The problem is in `'. $search . '`
and I don't know what is the correct form to enter variable in sparql query

Comment: the prefix has URI's links but i don't know here why not appearing

Comment: The question is modified

Comment: I also tried \"${search}\" and its not working any

Comment: Its solved its    ->    
 " ' . $search . ' ".